# mod_rewrite Error 500 for some though file without rewrites does not give error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to setup a rewrite from /api/user{/id} to api/user.php{/id} but for some reason it doesn't work. I suppose it's an internal rewrite loop but I don't know how to fix it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?api\/user\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+)?
RewriteRule ^\/?api\/user\/?(.*)?$ api/user.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Folder structure:

```
api/
api/user.php
```

When I change the rewrite rule so that it's not user but user2, it works without a problem. However, that's not what I need so it'd be kind if you could help me finding a solution to keep the naming.
This here is working with user**2**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?api\/user2\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+)?
RewriteRule ^\/?api\/user2\/?(.*)?$ api/user.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: "I suppose it's an internal rewrite loop"... this is not how you develop web pages. Guessing is not a debugging strategy. You need to find out. The first thing you _always_ do when you encounter a http 500 status is to look into your http server's error logfile where you can simply real what the actual issue is.

Comment: The actual issue is that your condition again matches `/api/user.php...`, since everything trailing the "user" is optional because of the question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?api/user(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9_/-]*))?$ /api/user.php/$1 [END]
```

It matches `/api/user` and `/api/user/` without capturing anything. For every longer requested URL the remainder is matched against the character group you specified.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Replacing END with L works. My setup is a fresh standard cPanel installation on CentOS7.
May you explain your regex? Also, does this make the RewriteCond obsolete?

Comment: I had to escape the slashes to work: ^\/?api\/user(?:\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]*))?$

Comment: Escaping the slashes is not required for the apache http server's module. It might be that cPanel interferes here. It is many such bugs.

Comment: Explain the regular expression? What exactly in it is that you are stumbling about? It is anchored to the literal prefix `/api/user`, where the leading slash is optional to make it match in both cases, distributed configuration files (".htaccess") and in the real configuration (absolute versus relative path, I assume you read the documentation of the tool you use...). Then everything that follows is optional _including_ the slash following the "user". But only the part following _that_ slash is captured (into `$1`) which you can cite in the target.